# phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured

Tags: windows, phpmyadmin

I have installed xampp 5.6.14 on windows. I open phpmyadmin http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

but warning

> ! The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
>   some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
>         Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.
>
> ! You are connected as 'root' with no password, which corresponds to the
>   default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with
>   this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this
>   security hole by setting a password for user 'root'.

How to solve it?

UPDATE:
I see my issue in [PMA Database ... not OK in phpMyAdmin upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033059/pma-database-not-ok-in-phpmyadmin-upgrade) but i don't understand. When I create database with contents in "create_tables.sql" by sql query in phpmyadmin but it's error

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_users` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`)
) 
  COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_usergroups` (
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
) 
  COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_navigationhiding` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
) 
  COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Error

SQL query:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_users` (   `username` varchar(64) NOT
>   NULL,   `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY
>   (`username`,`usergroup`) )    COMMENT='Users and their assignments to
>   user groups'   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 1046 - No database selected

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a widely asked question, please do your own research, before asking. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=phpMyAdmin+configuration+storage+is+not+completely+configured might already solve your problem.

Comment: @sec_aw: I'm using WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM. This is linux :(. They are different.

Comment: Please, do some research. This question has been asked multiple times. I updated my link above, it will take you to the stack overflow search results on "phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured".

Comment: Sorry, but your comment is very unreadable. Please edit your question and format the code you have problems with appropriately. BTW it says 'No database selected' so you probably have no database selected. Sorry, but I can not help you any further. Please do more research (there is plenty of information about this on the internet) or make your question clear so that people can follow through, what you have tried and might possibly help you.

Comment: @sec_aw: Sorry about that. [Link](http://tech.enekochan.com/en/2015/02/06/fix-configuration-pmadb-not-ok-phpmyadmin/)
How to implement `mysql -u root -p < create_tables.sql`. Thank you.

Answer (score 29):

resolving configuration storage problem in xampp in windows :

go to import tab in `localhost/phpmyadmin` and

browse `xampp\phpMyAdmin\sql` folder and select `create_tables.sql` and

then click go button

now phpmyadmin db added to your db list

now we must create user account for this db :

users tab and click add user

> name : pma

> password : pmapass

and click go

for privilege of this user create a file : `pma_privileges.sql`

with this content :

```sql
GRANT USAGE 
ON mysql.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT 
SELECT
( Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv, File_priv, Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv, Super_priv, Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv, Repl_client_priv ) 
   ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT 
SELECT
   ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT 
SELECT
(Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv) 
   ON mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT 
SELECT
,
   INSERT,
   UPDATE
,
      DELETE
         ON phpmyadmin.* TO 'pma'@'localhost';
```

and import it by import tab

now we create db and user with privilege so now

we must add them to config.inc.php file in xampp\phpMyAdmin folder

so add these :

```php
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';
    
    /* Storage database and tables */
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma__bookmark';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma__relation';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma__table_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma__table_coords';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma__pdf_pages';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma__column_info';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma__history';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma__table_uiprefs';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma__tracking';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma__userconfig';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma__recent';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['favorite'] = 'pma__favorite';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['savedsearches'] = 'pma__savedsearches';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['central_columns'] = 'pma__central_columns';
```

now restart the mysql and browser and the configuration storage error disappear and

columns after comment in creating table are visible

Comment: In `pma_privileges.sql` you have a syntax error:  `Unrecognized statement type. (near "ON" at position 0)`

Comment: With each step I got more and more errors

Comment: Worked like a charm.+1

Answer (score 27):

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
> some extended features have been deactivated. **Find out why**. Or
> alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

After did some searching on Google, it worked for me.

First,go to folder `xampp` > `phpmyadmin` > `config.inc.php`

Then, search (ctrl + F) for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']`. Change it to `root` or any user you have added. I just put `root`.

And for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']`, I left it blank because my root user doesn't have password. This will make the error/warning above dissapear.

Lastly, there will probably warning like

> The secret passphrase in configuration (blowfish_secret) is too short,

Just replace the `$cfg['blowfish_secret']` with a random string that is at least 32 characters long. For reference,

https://www.mysysadmintips.com/linux/servers/779-the-secret-passphrase-in-configuration-blowfish-secret-is-too-short

Comment: #1194 - Table 'tables_priv' is marked as crashed and should be repaired

Comment: This is solution for me.

Comment: correct solution! ;)

Answer (score 3):

The officially distributed `create_tables.sql` script includes a line to create and use the 'phpmyadmin' database, so perhaps XAMPP changes things.

Note that I don't use XAMPP and I expected that their installer would have set this all up for you, so there may be something wrong there that should be fixed in a more proper way, but one possible solution might be to download the [official phpMyAdmin version](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/sql/create_tables.sql) of `create_tables.sql` and use that, or you could just add the following line at the top of your sql file:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `phpmyadmin`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
USE phpmyadmin;
```

Answer (score 2):

First in phpMyAdmin go to users -> search the user **"root"** and host **"localhost".**
then select option -> edit privileges 
after that go to -> change password
set your password for root there.

then go to 
xampp folder -> phpmyadmin -> config.inc.php 
change config to cookie.
and password to your new password.
`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';  ----> cookie
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';   -----> new password(what you set for user root)`

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to enable the advanced features (using the latest version 3.4.x)

First login to phpmyadmin and create a new database called phpmadmin. When you have created the database select the import tab at the top of the page. Click the Browse/Choose file button and navigate to your phpmyadmin folder and open the scripts directory and select the create_tables.sql file. Click open to close the window. Then press Go (bottom of page). The database for the control user has been setup.

Next to setup the control user. Go to the phpmyadmin home screen and click the privileges tab. Click the add a new user link. For the username type phpmyadmin. Set anything as the password (Make sure you remember it). Choose the option to Create database with same name and grant all privileges And then click the Go button.

You have now setup the control user and the database for phpmyadmin. You now need to configure phpmyadmin. Open the config file (called config.inc.php). And remove the // from the start of the following lines

```
/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pmapass';

/* Storage database and tables */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
```

Make sure you set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` to `phpmyadmin` and apply the password to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']`. Log out of phpmyadmin, then log back in (not as the control user). The advanced features should now be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Visit the C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php and open this and set your own username and password, by default the username - 'root' and password - ' ',

and then restart your xammp server.

when you create the database schema at that time you have to remember the username and password for the next process

Answer (score 1):

[IMAGE , set like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c30A6.png)

easy, go to user account and change user pma@localhost to all privileges

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. change `xampp` installaion folder name to `xampp-org`.
2. re-install the same version of xampp in same directory as `xampp`.
3. Run "Apache" and "MySQL" in xampp control panel.
4. login phpMyAdmin with username `root`and blank password.
5. create a test DB as `freshDB`.
6. Stop all xampp services from control panel. And Quit it.
7. Go to `xampp\phpMyAdmin` and copy "config.in.php"
8. paste to the old installation folder re-named as `xampp-org`.
9. Now re-name the `xampp` folder to `xampp-new`. and `xampp-org` to `xampp`.
10. Run xampp as administrator from windows apps. Start xampp services
11. Login to phpMyAdmin with your custom username and password. (if not work then use username `root` and blank password).
12. If it worked and saved your time then `upVote` this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop Xampp services.
2. Go to 'C:\xampp\mysql'.
3. Rename 'data' folder to 'data.old'
4. There should be a folder named 'backup' in 'C:\xampp\mysql'. Copy and paste it there. A copy folder will be created, then rename it as 'data'. Do not use 'backup' folder directly as you might need it in future for the same purpose.
5. Now copy 'ibdata1' file from 'data.old' to the newly created 'data' folder.
6. Databases created by you are kept in folder 'C:\xampp\mysql\data' as a separate folder. For example if you've created a database named 'test' then 'C:\xampp\mysql\data' should also have a folder named 'test'. So copy all the database folders that you've created from 'data.old' to new 'data' folder. Remember do not copy 'phpmyadmin', 'performance_schema' or 'mysql' folder, as they are created by phpmyadmin not by you.
7. Start Xampp services.
8. It should be working fine now. Then you can delete 'data.old' folder if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I just restarted phpMyAdmin, and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

On your PC

1. Go to the Xampp directory from your drive
2. Navigate to the MySQL folder
3. Navigate to the data folder: C:\xampp\mysql\data
4. You will be able to see the name of the database as a folder, you can delete it forever, or cut it and paste it somewhere different
5. Refresh the phpMyAdmin page, the error is gone