# The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured

Tags: php, google-chrome, phpmyadmin, xampp

> The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured,
>   some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why. Or
>   alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.

I get this error message.

when I click find out why I get this:

> Configuration of pmadb… not OK General relation features Disabled

I followed the instructions here [phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33824224/phpmyadmin-configuration-storage-is-not-completely-configured) and tried to create an account with name pma and password pmapass but I get

> An account already exists with the same username but possibly a
>   different hostname
>    no accounts exist with that name though